# Tight instance for unweighted maximum coverage problem?

Tags: algorithms, reductions

The [maximum (unweighted) coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem) is defined as follows:

- **Instance**: A number $k$ and a collection of sets $S = \{S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_m\}$.
- **Objective**: Find a subset $S^{'} \subseteq S$ of sets, such that $\left| S^{'} \right| \leq k$ and the number of covered elements $\left| \bigcup_{S_i \in S^{'}}{S_i} \right|$ is maximized.

This problem is NP-hard. I am trying to find a counterexample when the greedy algorithm fails but I failed. Especially, can you find a family of instances when the greedy algorithm always fails? (Or at least one simple instance?)

- **The greedy algorithm:**
  at each stage, choose a set which contains the largest number of uncovered elements.

I found a family of instances [here](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~dasgupta/resume/publ/papers/allpages.pdf) but it was for the weighted case and I cannot transform it to the unweighted case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one example:
take the universe   $$U=\{u_1,\dots,u_n,v_1,\dots,v_n\}$$
$S_i=\{u_i,v_i\}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ , and  $S_{n+1}=\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$, $m=n+1$, $k=n$